# SVG Wrapping text on x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to wrap some text on a bar graph i am creating using D3.

https://jsfiddle.net/4j27311q/2/

i have a fiddle for the same but due to some error the text is not wrapping. As my label have no spaces instead have '_', so i am trying to use them as separator. 
i am using the same statergy as suggested by 'https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321'

How to align them right.?

Here's the fiddle i am trying to work with:

```
    var wrap = function(text, width) {

 text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/_/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join("_"));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: I actually changed the question.. i am able to get the wrap working but the alignment of the labels is completely off.. and i am looking for suggestion to see how best i can adjust them on the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `wrap` function, which is clearly working (as you can see by simply removing its `call`).

The issue here is way more prosaic: `rotate` will rotate the element around the origin of the coordinates system. There are several ways for fixing this, the easiest one being simply setting the x and y position in the same `transform` function, using `translate`:

```
.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(-40,30) rotate(-60)"
})
```

I'm using magic numbers here because your code is full of them!

Here is the demo:

```js
var wrap = function(text, width) {

  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split("_").reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join("_"));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });

}



var tempData = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
  var obj = {

    "Id": 1,
    "Type": 'Apple_Orange_Swiss_Some_Things_' + i,
    "Count": 5
  };
  tempData.push(obj);
}


var barWidth = 30,
  paddingFactor = 2.2,
  padding = 20,
  responsiveDIVHeight = 300,
  responsiveDIVWidth = tempData.length * barWidth * paddingFactor;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, responsiveDIVWidth], 0.5)
  .domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type
  })),
  y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([responsiveDIVHeight - padding, padding])
  .domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
    return (d.Count + 10);
  })]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom'),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left');


var svgY = d3.select('#verticalSVG')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', responsiveDIVHeight)
  .attr("width", 50);

svgY.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis)
  .attr('dx', '-0.3em')
  .attr('transform', "translate(50, 0)");;

var svgX = d3.select('#horizontalSVG')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', responsiveDIVWidth)
  .attr('height', responsiveDIVHeight + 300);

svgX.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', "translate(0," + (responsiveDIVHeight - padding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(-40,30) rotate(-60)"
  }).call(wrap, 90);


var startPoint = 0;

var bar = svgX.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(tempData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return y(d.Count)
  })
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return x(d.Type)
  })
  .attr('width', barWidth)
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return responsiveDIVHeight - y(d.Count) - padding
  })
```

```css
.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <div id="verticalSVG" style="float:left">

    </div>
    <div id="horizontalSVG" style="overflow-x:scroll">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hmm!! i actually tried this but not sure why it did not worked for me!!!.. (let me take a look at my code)..and yeah i need to work on those magic numbers you have mentioned.. I am trying to get something going before i start using actual height and widths...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...the problem i had was due to the getcomputedtextlength...the div i was rendering in my angular directive was hidden when the graph was processed and so the length wascoming as zero...I will mark this as answer as this solves my issue but yeah the fixed numbers i am using needs to be fixed..Thanks for the help